# LaTeX Error: File 'baposter.cls' not found

Tags: errors, miktex, document-classes, posters

It appears when I try to build file in MiKTeX 2.9 I get

```
LaTeX Error: File 'baposter.cls' not found
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name.(Default extension:cls))
Enter file name:
```

Comment: see http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/ you can download the package form there; place in your working directory or anywhere where latex can find it.

Answer (score 9):

[`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/) is not available from CTAN. As such it is not available in either the TeX Live of MiKTeX distribution. Download [`baposter.cls`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter.cls), place it in your working folder and recompile.

For some example usages and information, see the [`baposter` documentation](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter_guide.pdf).

Comment: Is there any specific reason why it would not be available from CTAN? (Perhaps licensing issues?)